# How to calculate volume under 3D-surface in R

Tags: r, 3d, volume, landscape, surface

I'd like to calculate the volume under my surface in R, but don't know how...
My example data:

```
set.seed(94756)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:1000,500,replace = TRUE),ncol = 20)  
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)

library(dplyr)
fig1 <- add_column(mat, id = seq(0.2, nrow(mat)*0.2,0.2), .before = "V1")
fig2 <- rbind(seq(0, ncol(fig1)*2,2), fig1) 


colnames(fig2) <- fig2[1,]
fig2 <- fig2[2:nrow(fig2),]

row.names(fig2) <- fig2$`0`
fig2[1] <- NULL


library(plotly)
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
df <- plot_ly(z = ~mat)
df <- df %>% add_surface()
df
```

I think I have to create a block with min, max and calculate with integrals. But not sure how exactly...
If anyone can, it would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This surface is highly non-smooth. Is it you real case?

Comment: No it's not. But my real surface is non-smooth as well :)

Comment: please include the packages needed to run your example. Where can I find `add_column`?

Comment: I have a technique described on [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/volumeUnderSurface.html) but not sure it is reliable for a non-smooth surface.

Answer (score 0):

The function underlying `mat` is a constant piecewise function defined on a regular grid. As for OP request, `mat` should contain also NAs to better represent actual data.

```r
  set.seed(94756)
  ## generate a matrix with ~ 5% of missing values
  mat <- matrix(ifelse(runif(500) < 0.05,
                       NA,
                       sample(1:1000,500,replace = TRUE)),
                ncol = 20)
```

As a simple option to deal with missing values, I am replacing them with the median value of `mat`:

```r
  ## replace NA with the median value
  mat[is.na(mat)] <- median(mat, na.rm = 1)
```

Let's assume the area of each tile of the grid is `gridArea`, your integral is:

```r
  gridArea <- 0.2 * 2
  sum(gridArea * mat)

  # [1] 98727.2
```

Comment: hmm...actually the grid for my original data is 2 to 0.2 I guess, means that x-data has a distance of 2 cm and y data has a distance of 2mm. Also NA is included sometimes...

Comment: @timtams if you edit your question, including grid size etc., I will try to update my answer.

Comment: I just did, but I don't know how to bring NA into the dataset. So NA's are missing till now

Comment: @timtams That's good because you can't calculate an integral with NAs

Comment: So how can I handle NA's in my original dataset?

Comment: @timtams you need to impute missing values somehow

Comment: sounds difficult... I would call myself still a beginner in R

Comment: And the result of sum(gridArea * mat) gives me the volume of my 3D model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242261/discussion-between-sbarbit-and-timtams).